# Equal Strings in C++

Tags: c++, string

I am reversing a string and comparing it to another string whether it matches or not.
String *d* is reversed correctly, but in the *If* statement, it is not comparing. Strings comparing like this usually works I have done it before. Can someone explain this?
Thank You

```
    int main()
{   
    string a, d, e;
    int b, c;
    cin >> a >> e;
    for (int i = a.size(); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        d.push_back(a[i]);
    }
    cout << d;
    if (d == e)
        cout << "YES";
    else
        cout << "NO";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are pushing the NUL terminator in `a` to the start of `d`. What did you debugger tell you?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the `i = a.size()` when used in `d.push_back(a[i]);` will lead to undesired subscript access (*recall that indexing starts with 0, while `size()` returns the amount of elements in a container*).

You should look toward this implementation:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{   
    std::string a, d, e;
    int b, c;
    std::cin >> a >> e;
    for (auto i = a.rbegin(); i != a.rend(); ++i) // Using return iterators
    {
        d.push_back(*i); // Dereference the iterator and push_back() it
    }
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
    if (d == e)
        std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "NO" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Example:

```
foo
oof
oof
YES
```

This approach uses [reverse iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) on the string. Note, in order to advance this type of iterator, you use the same increment operation, only in this case, the iterator goes backwards (from the end of container to beginning).

Comment: `a.size()-1` bad things will happen if `a` is empty.

Answer (score 2):

If a string is 4 characters long, then `s[4]` will give you 1 past the end of the string. So here:

```
for (int i = a.size(); i >= 0; i--)
```

when you use `i` which would be 4 in the first step, you are accessing past the end of the string. You could do:

```
for (int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

but be careful if `a` is empty! You will underflow the integer and end up with big problems! You could check for empty string at the top of your function but that is extra work. To avoid this problem, you could use an iterator, but these only go forward :( Oh wait, reverse_iterator!

```
for (auto rit = s.rbegin(); rit != s.rend(); ++rit) {
    d.push_back(*rit);
```

This will solve the problem. You could wrap this up in a function, call it reverse! Luckily, this actually exists: [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse):

```
a = d;
std::reverse(std::begin(d), std::end(d));
```

Easy peasy

Comment: `a.size() - 1` is naughty. I use the `-->` idiom for this sort of thing, but it can irritate some folk.

Comment: @Bathsheba, yeah, i am getting to reverse iterators

Comment: Personally I'd remove the second part of the answer altogether.

Comment: As in using `size`?

Comment: Yup, just tin the bit from "You need to do:", Any binary `-` with an unsigned type ias one of the arguments is best avoided really.

Comment: You can also use `std::ranges::ssize` or `std::ssize`. That will return a signed integer.

Comment: @Bathsheba I figured it was worth going through some solutions

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili you should add this as a separate answer

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you accessing the NUL terminator of `a`, and putting that at the start of `d`. The behaviour of your program was undefined up to but not including C++11.

Using

```
a = d;
std::reverse(std::begin(d), std::end(d));
```

is the solution. Alternatives such as character by character access are poor due to the potential pitfalls with using unsigned arithmetic. Using the C++ standard library can also help your compiler in its optimisation choices.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reversing the string then comparing, you could compare the strings using [std::equal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal):

```
bool result = std::equal(a.rbegin(), a.rend(),
                         d.begin(), d.end());
```

Comment: You're late to the party, but yes I like this a lot. Smartypants ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba, thanks. Your answer inspired me. I liked the in-place reverse operation and your solution still uses a [lexicographical compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp), I think. My solution will work for ASCII but umlauts and other modifiers will cause problems once you start using Unicode, I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to check if the string is a palindrome, you don't need to allocate a new string. Here's a much more efficient way:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string_view>

[[nodiscard]] constexpr bool IsPalindrome(std::string_view const str) noexcept {
  auto begin = str.begin();
  auto mid = begin + str.size() / 2;
  return std::equal(begin, mid, str.rbegin());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual idiom for writing a loop is to start at the beginning and stop when you've passed the last element. With an index it looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
    // do something with a[i]
}
```

Note that the terminating condition becomes true when `i` goes off the end.

To do that when you want to go in the other direction you have two choices:

```
for (int i = a.size(); i > 0; --i) {
    // do something with a[i - 1]
}
```

In this case, the element we're interested in is `a[i - 1]`. The loop starts with the topmost element, when `i` is `a.size()`, and stops after the last element, when `i` becomes 0 and accessing `a[i - 1]` would be off the end.

That's a bit tricky to visualize, so you might be tempted to write it like this instead:

```
for (int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    // do something with a[i]
}
```

This version has a subtle bug, and should not be your usual approach. The problem is that `a.size()` is **unsigned**. When `a` is empty, `a.size()` is 0, and `a.size() - 1` wraps around and becomes a very large value. So don't use it.

Another way to avoid problems like this is to use iterators, which handle the details of recognizing the beginning and end of the sequence:

```
for (auto iter = std::begin(a); iter != std::end(a); ++iter) {
    // do something with *iter
}
```

This is easily adapted to reverse iteration:

```
for (auto iter = std::rbegin(a); iter != std::rend(a); ++iter) {
    // do something with *iter
}
```

And yet another possibility is to let the standard library handle the iteration:

```
void do_someting_with_a_sub_i(int) {
    // whatever
}

std::for_each(std::begin(a), std::end(a), do_someting_with_a_sub_i);
```

or, in reverse,

```
std::for_each(std::rbegin(a), std::rend(a), do_someting_with_a_sub_i);
```

(yes, modern fashion calls for using a lambda instead of writing out `do_something_with_a_sub_i`. Sigh.)